# "Parameter" @: in makefile is incorrect?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The line `@:` in the following makefile snippet causes

```
make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect.
Makefile:210: recipe for target 'depend' failed
```

(Line 210 is the first instance of `@:`)

Why?

```
# We check if any depfile is newer than Makefile and decide to
# concatenate only if that is true.
depend:
    @: 
    @if egrep "^# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE" Makefile >/dev/null && [ -z "`find $(DEPS) -newer Makefile 2>/dev/null; exit 0`" ]; then :; else \
      ( $(PERL) -pe 'exit 0 if /^# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE.*/' < Makefile; \
        echo '# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend depends on it.'; \
        echo; \
        for f in $(DEPS); do \
          if [ -f $$f ]; then cat $$f; fi; \
        done ) > Makefile.new; \
      if cmp Makefile.new Makefile >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
        rm -f Makefile.new; \
      else \
        mv -f Makefile.new Makefile; \
      fi; \
    fi
    @:
```

`make -v` gives the following version information

```
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using a version of GNU make (3.82.90) which is not only old, but more importantly it's a pre-release version (all the x.x.9x release numbers are alpha/beta releases for the next major release).  You should at least switch to a real release of GNU make: pre-releases have bugs and issues which were resolved before the final release.

However, your problem likely is that you're building on Windows and your makefile was written for a UNIX/POSIX system.  In a POSIX shell, the `:` command is a no-op command so the sequence `@:` means don't print the command (make's `@` prefix) followed by a shell do-nothing command (`:`).  I don't know why it's there in your makefile, but clearly the version of make you're using is not invoking a POSIX shell, so it doesn't know about this command.